# Wicket calendar incomprehensible behavior

Tags: java, calendar, wicket

hi i have one incomprehensible problem with wicket. Concretly with JQuery UI calendar for wicket described below.

http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/calendar/DefaultCalendarPage?5

My code:

calendar = new Calendar("calendar",new MainContentCalendarModel(), options) {

```
        @Override
        public boolean isEventClickEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onEventClick(AjaxRequestTarget target, CalendarView view, int eventId) {
            MainContentCalendarEvent event = CalendarDao.getEvent(eventId);
            if (event != null) {
                dialog.setModelObject(event);
                dialog.open(target);
            }


}
};
```

---

UPDATE:
default methods implemetntation:

```
public boolean isSelectable() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isDayClickEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEventDropEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEventResizeEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isObjectDropEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isViewRenderEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
```

i don't know why i can resize and drag event in calendar ...how can i that behavior turn off? pls help :) full code you can find [here:https://github.com/sebfz1/wicket-jquery-ui](https://github.com/sebfz1/wicket-jquery-ui). thx...

Answer (score 0):

These methods should be **inside** Calendar, e.g.:

```
new Calendar("calendar",new MainContentCalendarModel(), options) {


        @Override
        public boolean isEventClickEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onEventClick(AjaxRequestTarget target, CalendarView view, int eventId) {
            MainContentCalendarEvent event = CalendarDao.getEvent(eventId);
            if (event != null) {
                dialog.setModelObject(event);
                dialog.open(target);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isSelectable() {
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Add `@Override` to them to make sure they actually override something ;-)

Comment: yes but... default value of isSelectable is false ...and other too ... than i think it is not  necessary  :) ... but first what i try, was it

Comment: Please create a mini demo application, e.g. in GitHub.